# Remove Spacing between rows

Tags: android, android-layout

hi i am developing a small calculator app and i want to remove spacing between rows and columns of the button i want calculator buttons to be attached to each other.just like floor tiles i am using Grid Layout but still  there is small amount of space left between any  two buttons

This is layout xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    
   <EditText 
       android:id="@+id/calc_board"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:inputType="text"/>

   <GridLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_margin="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="2"
       android:columnCount="4"
       android:rowCount="5"
       android:useDefaultMargins="false" >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/clear_btn"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:layout_column="0"
           android:layout_row="0"
           android:text="@string/clear_btn"
           android:textSize="25sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/cross_btn"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:layout_column="1"
           android:layout_row="0"
           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_backspace"
           android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_backspace"
           android:textSize="20sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/divide_btn"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:layout_column="2"
           android:layout_row="0"
           android:text="@string/divide_btn"
           android:textSize="30sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/multiply_btn"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:layout_column="3"
           android:layout_row="0"
           android:text="@string/mult_btn"
           android:textSize="30sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/seven_btn"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:layout_column="0"
           android:layout_row="1"
           android:text="@string/seven_btn"
           android:textSize="25sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/eight_btn"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:layout_column="1"
           android:layout_row="1"
           android:text="@string/eight_btn"
           android:textSize="25sp" />
   </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Apply `android:clipToPadding="false"` to your parent layout or apply background color to your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be because you are setting your buttons to be specific sizes.  I'll explain in the horizontal direction for simplicity, but the same thing is essentially happening in the vertical direction.  For horizontal direction, you are specifying 80dp as the button width, but you have your gridlayout width set to match_parent.  If your buttons don't fill the width of the total actual size allocated to them by the grid layout based on it's total width (which in the layout you have defined is determined by the width of the screen), you could end up with extra space around the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you seem to specify a fixed width and height for button sizes. If you use specific height and width it may look different on different screens.

You can use LinearLayout instead of GridLayout like below.

I think this might help you.. :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/calc_board"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clear_btn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clear_bt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clear_bn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clea"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clea1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clea2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clea3r_bn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clea4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```